# Rename a count column in a group by pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this:

```
EID  TERM  
1    2      
1    2
2    2
3    2
1    3
2    3
3    3
```

What I would like to do is something similar to this SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(EID) AS EVENT_COUNT, EID, TERM
FROM TABLE1   
GROUP BY EID, TERM
```

The results would look like

```
EVENT_COUNT  EID  TERM  
2             1    2      
1             2    2
1             3    2
1             1    3
1             2    3
1             3    3
```

My Python Code looks like this:

```
 new_df = df.groupby(["EID","TERM"]).agg({"EID":"count"})
```

I get the counts fine but can't rename the column, so when I write this data frame to a csv my output header looks like this:

```
EID,TERM,EID
```

How do I rename the count column (last EID) to say EVENT_COUNT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate on the EID column only and use to_frame to rename.

```
(
    df.groupby(["EID","TERM"]).EID.count()
    .to_frame('EVENT_COUNT')
    .reset_index()
    [['EVENT_COUNT','EID','TERM']]
)
```

Of you can use namedagg (works above pandas 0.24):

```
(
    df.groupby(["EID","TERM"])
    .agg(EVENT_COUNT=("EID", "count"))
    .reset_index()
    [['EVENT_COUNT','EID','TERM']]
)
```